# Custom User without Sessions

Tags: django

In Django 1.5, I would like to create a custom user by subclassing AbstractUser. However I can't figure out how to do this and diable sessions at the same time, as Django seems to have a mess of dependencies. Note: I have tried removing 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware' from the MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES tuple in settings.py.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at how this guy disables sessions for some requests by using middleware: [Disable session creation in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052473/disable-session-creation-in-django)

You could use that, but for all requests instead.

Comment: Thank you that is very helpful. I would up-vote but I lack privilege