# How to prevent Django from writing to django_session table for certain URLs

Tags: django, session, django-sessions

Apologies if my question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052473/disable-session-creation-in-django) and my approach to trying to solve the issue is 100% based on the answers to that question but I think this is slightly more involved and may target a part of Django that I do not fully understand.

---

I have a CMS system written in Django 1.5 with a few APIs accessible by two desktop applications which cannot make use of cookies as a browser does.

I noticed that every time an API call is made by one of the applications (once every 3 seconds), a new entry is added to `django_session` table. Looking closely at this table and the code, I can see that all entries to a specific URL are given the same `session_data` value but a different `session_key`. This is probably because Django determines that when one of these calls is made from a cookie-less application, the `request.session._session_key` is `None`.

The result of this is that thousands of entries are created every day in `django_session` table and simply running `./manage clearsessions` using a daily cron will not remove them from this table, making whole database quite large for no obvious benefit. Note that I even tried `set_expiry(1)` for these requests, but `./manage clearsessions` still doesn't get rid of them.

To overcome this problem through Django, I've had to override 3 Django middlewares as I'm using SessionMiddleware, AuthenticationMiddleware and MessageMiddleware:

```
from django.contrib.sessions.middleware import SessionMiddleware
from django.contrib.auth.middleware import AuthenticationMiddleware
from django.contrib.messages.middleware import MessageMiddleware

class MySessionMiddleware(SessionMiddleware):
    def process_request(self, request):
        if ignore_these_requests(request):
            return
        super(MySessionMiddleware, self).process_request(request)

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        if ignore_these_requests(request):
            return response
        return super(MySessionMiddleware, self).process_response(request, response)

class MyAuthenticationMiddleware(AuthenticationMiddleware):
    def process_request(self, request):
        if ignore_these_requests(request):
            return
        super(MyAuthenticationMiddleware, self).process_request(request)

class MyMessageMiddleware(MessageMiddleware):
    def process_request(self, request):
        if ignore_these_requests(request):
            return
        super(MyMessageMiddleware, self).process_request(request)

def ignore_these_requests(request):
    if request.POST and request.path.startswith('/api/url1/'):
            return True
    elif request.path.startswith('/api/url2/'):
        return True
    return False
```

Although the above works, I can't stop thinking that I may have made this more complex that it really is and that this is not the most efficient approach as 4 extra checks are made for every single request.

Are there any better ways to do the above in Django? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Other solutions would include changing the session engine or session lifetime.

Comment: Can you distinguish the non-session-aware clients based on HTTP headers? (User-Agent for example)

Comment: @Thomas I tried to change the session lifetime by running set_expiry(1) but for some reason, running ./manage clearsessions doesn't clear those - not too sure why

Comment: @gertvdijk that could work but would I not need to create checks for HTTP headers in the 3 middlewares similar to the above approach?

Comment: @purplemass Yes. However, a dirty hack would be defining a custom new middleware listed *after* SessionMiddleware, deleting the session object, e.g. `del request.session`. In combination with leaving [`settings.SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST) to `False` this should prevent the session from being written to the database (despite being created first).

Comment: @ gertvdijk that sounds like a good solution, thanks. I'll try it now. I expect, I'll have to list this custom middleware after MessageMiddleware

Comment: @gertvdijk that worked! Nice solution: one middleware that is listed right at the end of the middleware list and deletes the session if `request.META['HTTP_COOKIE']` is not set - I'll list this as the accepted answer later on

Comment: @purplemass Okay, I'm writing an answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Dirty hack: removing session object conditionally.

One approach would be including a single middleware discarding the session object conditional to the request. It's a bit of a dirty hack for two reasons:

- The Session object is created at first and removed later. (inefficient)
- You're relying on the fact that the Session object isn't written to the database yet at that point. This may change in future Django versions (though not very likely).

---

Create a [custom middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/):

```
class DiscardSessionForAPIMiddleware(object):

    def process_request(self, request):
        if request.path.startswith("/api/"): # Or any other condition
            del request.session
```

Make sure you install this *after* the `django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware` in the `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` tuple in your `settings.py`.

Also check that [`settings.SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST) is set to `False` (the default). This makes it delay the write to the database until the data is modified.

---

Alternatives (untested)

- Use `process_view` instead of `process_request` in the custom middleware so you can check for the view instead of the request path. Advantage: condition check is better. Disadvantage: other middleware might already have done something with the session object and then this approach fails.
- Create a custom decorator (or a shared base class) for your API views deleting the session object in there. Advantage: responsibility for doing this will be with the views, the place where you probably like it best (view providing the API). Disadvantage: same as above, but deleting the session object in an even later stage.

Comment: Thanks very much for this @gertvdijk. I used the first method you suggested but changed the condition to check for `request.META['HTTP_COOKIE']` as our desktop applications do not set this in their requests. Also, as I'm using Django's AuthenticationMiddleware and MessageMiddleware, I listed this custom middleware after MessageMiddleware.

Comment: Update: `request.META['HTTP_COOKIE']` is not the correct check to use as the first time a CMS user visits the site, this is empty. I replaced it with `request.META['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `settings.SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST` is set to `False`. That will go a long way in ensuring sessions aren't saved every time.

Also, if you have any ajax requests going to your server, ensure that the request includes the cookie information so that the server doesn't think each request belongs to a different person.

Comment: Thanks @Gevious - I double-checked the settings and found that `settings.SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST` is indeed set to `False`. I also checked the Ajax requests: all of these come from the CMS and seem to keep the session used by the browser, so no issues there.

Comment: Do you make any requests to external web services using something like curl? or do you simply receive requests from the browser and then return responses?

Comment: the requests in question are all from desktop applications written in C#/Unity done via HTTP. The CMS also has standard browser based users that also make use of these APIs