# How to add my logic when I access the `ListAPIView`?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I use the `BannerListAPIView` when access the banner list:

```
class BannerListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = WebsiteBannerSerializer
    permission_classes = []
    queryset = WebsiteBanner.objects.all()
```

But I want to add my logic when access this `ListAPIView`, such as I want to record the `remote_ip`.

How to add my logic when I access this `ListAPIView`?

---

**EDIT**

I just want to know where I can add my custom logic when user access the `ListAPIView`.

Answer (score 0):

you can override the `list()` function of your class like so:

```
class BannerListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = WebsiteBannerSerializer
    permission_classes = []
    queryset = WebsiteBanner.objects.all()

    def list(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # YOUR LOGIC
        return super(BannerListAPIView, self).list(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: `return super(WebsiteBannerSerializer, self).list(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type`  Why there is a error?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to record IPs for every request app-wide, you may want to look into using a [middleware] rather than doing this at the view level, which may be considered bad practice.

Comment: But I want to just when user access the home page API, then I record it. whether the middleware can realize this case?

Comment: you can use a [middleware decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916966/non-global-middleware-in-django)